# Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, 18.04, wifi-direct

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZkJtXSxwcX/
In the link you can find all the information regarding my wifi being shown in ubuntu 18.04. I am using Lenovo Y520.

Comment: As per the information in the link WiFi seem to be hard blocked. Find the network key on the keyboard and press it. Or try enabling wireless in BIOS

Comment: how do i enable wifi key in BIOS?

Comment: Evidently, Fn+F8 activates/deactivates Airplane Mode. Does that turn off Hard Blocked:Yes and activate the wireless? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c?id=5d9f40b56630a8702b5f7a61a770f9b73aa07464

Comment: @chili555 Although I don't have any lenovo laptop but by observing [this pic](https://www.lenovo.com/medias/ideapad-y520-gallery05.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxMjM4MzV8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xpbWFnZXMvaGVlL2gyOC85MzU5NzAwNTU3ODU0LmpwZ3wwZDU4NGFjZDYzZjY4NWZiMWY0Zjc4ZDdmMWQwM2YzZWQwOGQ5NzRiMzRmMDk1ZmI5ZjE0NTBlYTgwODlmY2Ji) I can surely say the key is F7 instead of F8 and sometimes Fn is also not required.

Comment: @gulzainkhan98 Open BIOS. Go to Configuration or Advance tab. Navigate to WLAN and enable that.

Comment: guys i know how to turn on and off my airplane mode. It's not working so i will try the BIOS solution.

Comment: Also, i don't think it will be a bios problem because i am using dual boot and wifi is working perfectly fine in Windows

Comment: We just wanted to verify that the Airplane Mode key combination was inoperable in Ubuntu. Does the wireless spring to life if you do: `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` If so, we can blacklist it.